# Prove series to the power of 5 by induction

Tags: induction, proof-explanation, power-series, summation-method

Prove by induction:

$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + n^5 = \frac{n^2 (n + 1)^2 (2n^2 + 2n − 1)}{12}  $$

I tried to solve it to some extent. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: What have you tried? The base case is obvious since $1^5=\frac{1\times 2^2\times 3}{12}=1$. Now you just need to prove that if it holds for $n=k$, then it holds for $n=k+1$. Are you having trouble with the inductive step? Please show us your working out.

Comment: Yes, I'm actually having problem to prove if it holds for n = k+1. I have arrived to a stage where it is,  1/12*(k+1)^2* [i^2(2*i^2 + 2*i -1) + 12 (k+1)^3)   .. I am stuck at this step.. if I expand from here, it looks ugly.

Comment: To prove a statement of the form $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n=b_n$ by induction, you merely need to check that (i) $a_1=b_1$ and (ii) $a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}-b_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
For the inductive step, you want to prove that if:

$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + k^5 = \frac{k^2 (k + 1)^2 (2k^2 + 2k − 1)}{12}  \tag{1}$$

Then the following is also true:

$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + k^5+(k+1)^5 = \frac{(k+1)^2 (k + 2)^2 (2k^2 + 6k +3)}{12}  \tag{2}$$

So let us first assume that equation $(1)$ is true. then:

$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + k^5+(k+1)^5 = \frac{k^2 (k + 1)^2 (2k^2 + 2k − 1)}{12}+(k+1)^5 $$
$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + k^5+(k+1)^5 = \frac{k^2 (k + 1)^2 (2k^2 + 2k − 1)+12(k+1)^5}{12}$$
$$ 1^5 + 2^5 + 3^5 + . . . + k^5+(k+1)^5 = \frac{(k+1)^2(k^2(2k^2+2k-1)+12(k+1)^3)}{12}$$

I will leave you to finish off the proof. The only thing you need to do now is to prove $k^2(2k^2+2k-1)+12(k+1)^3=(k+2)^2(2k^2 + 6k +3)$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have verified it for $n=1$

Now assume it is true for $n$ and then try to prove for $n+1$. Break the summation into two parts. One having $n$ terms and the other part being the $n+1^{th}$ term itself. Substitute the sum of $n$ terms from your assumption.

According to me, you should not have much difficulty in solving the problem by induction. There are some other elegant methods too as linked below.

1.[Method of undetermined coefficients](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-undetermined-coefficients/)

2.[Faulhaber's formula and other generalizations](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sum-of-n-n2-or-n3/)

Comment: Yes, I'm actually having problem to prove if it holds for n = k+1. I have arrived to a stage where it is, 1/12*(k+1)^2* [i^2(2*i^2 + 2*i -1) + 12 (k+1)^3) .. I am stuck at this step.. if I expand from here, it looks ugly.

Comment: It looks ugly, and it is also ugly to solve. But you have to do it. Otherwise you may refer the other methods. They are truly elegant

Answer (score 0):

$k^6-(k-1)^6=6k^5-15k^4+20k^3-15k^2+6k-1$, therefore,
$$
n^6=6\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^5-15\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^4+20\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3-15\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2+6\sum_{k=1}^{n}k-n
$$
I assume you know what $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^4$, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^3$,$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$ are. Actually you can apply this method again. Although it's not induction, it's much more convenient.